# Re-writing URL's with Query Parameters such as Product ID's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

There is so much content on the web for URL re-writes based on a number of scenario's that it makes it difficult to locate a solution to a specific query.

I'm just trying to clarify what the 'best' way to re-write URL's with query parameters to 'search engine friendly' URL's would be when using mod_rewrite on an apache server.

For example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/product.php?pid=130
```

Would something like the following in .htaccess rewrite the above URL to a search engine friendly version?

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pid=130$
RewriteRule ^$ /productid-130.html [L]
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, your question should go to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Second, you don't get how it works (reading your rewrite rules). It's the opposite.

Comment: And last but not least: please make sure you've read **everything** here before asking:

- Here's the wiki of [serverfault.com][1]
- The [howto's htaccess official guide][2]
- The [official mod_rewrite guide][3]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as
  [2]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html
  [3]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Probably the most unhelpful comment ever... :/ There's other questions about mod_rewrite on Stackoverflow else - why are the tags available for this then and why was there no prompt to post at the other site? How was I supposed to know there was a more suitable location for this topic unless the site tells me? Great, you've given a ton of documentation that I don't understand because I'm not a developer - why do you think I'm on here for support? My developers are on their Christmas holidays so I thought some kind bod at SO could help - evidently not!

Comment: You're **not a developper**, you're asking at Stackoverflow and you're surprised people give "developpers response"? My comment was everything but useless to a developper, man!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if it is a productid html url, then capture the productid
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/productid-([0-9]+)\.html$ [NC]
#and rewrite to product.php with id
RewriteRule . product.php?pid=%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ulrich. Wouldn't I need it to do the other way round? Capture the product id in the query parameter and then rewrite to search engine friendly URL (which would be the productid-130.html URL) - Or have I got that wrong? Thanks

Comment: No, it is the other way round. You want search engines (and people) to see the keyword rich URL `productid-130.html` (hence its called SEO-friendly). Internally, you treat it as a request to your application with parameters as usual